# Objective-c Property returns 'nil' in Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift

**audio.h**

```
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) int count;
```

**audio.m**

```
_count = 0; count++;
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
var audioSwift: audio?
print(audioSwift?.count)
```

This returns 'nil' and what I want is to have the modified valued

**-Bdridging-Header.h**

```
#import "audio.h"
```

What to do?
Thank you!

Comment: It's `nil` because you never created an instance of `audio`?

Comment: I just edited,
var audioSwift: audio?
print(audioSwift?.count)

Comment: var audioSwift = audio()

Comment: that returns "error: memory read failed for 0x0"

Comment: declare variable as `var audioSwift = audio()` // class.

Comment: okay that works, I just need to fix my code 
thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't post answers in comments.

Here is a complete answer:

The problem is that you never create an audio object, so your `audioSwift` variable is indeed nil.

Change your Swift code like this:

```
var audioSwift = audio()  //Create a new audio object. 
print(audioSwift.count)
```

Since the code above creates an audio object right away, it doesn't need to be an Optional any more.

Note that in both Swift and Objective-C class names should start with an upper-case letter, so your `audio` class should be named `Audio` instead.